# How to catch Python UDF exceptions when using PyArrow

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions, pyarrow

When PyArrow is enabled, Pandas UDF exceptions raised by the Executor become impossible to catch: see example below. Is this expected behavior?

If so, what is the rationale. If not, how do I fix this?

Confirmed behavior in PyArrow 0.11 and 0.14.1 (latest) and PySpark 2.4.0 and 2.4.3. Python 3.6.5.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# setting this to false will allow the exception to be caught
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

@udf
def disrupt(x):
    raise Exception("Test EXCEPTION")

data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3]}))

try:
    test = data.withColumn("test", disrupt("A")).toPandas()
except:
    print("exception caught")

print('end')
```

I expect the broad except to catch each and every exception.

Answer (score 2):

Update: as far as I understand this is by design, but if anyone has any other ideas I'd love to hear from you. I.e. is it possible to make PyArrow direct the exception error log someplace else?

Comment: Check the results? e.g. pq.write_to_dataset(df, root_path=path); dataset=pq.ParquetDataset(path). If there is an error, there will be an exception. I know it's not ideal but like you said, so far no good solution to it.